# Where is GL_TEXTURE_MIN_LOD on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, textures, mipmaps

Is there an equivalent ? Is it an iPhone limitation or
an OpenGL version limitation ? I can't find the mipmap level
feature anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ES 1.1 [doesn't support it](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/1.1/docs/man/glTexParameter.xml).

Though you might [check](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/1.1/docs/man/glGetString.xml) if your implementation has [EXT_texture_lod_bias](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL/extensions/EXT/EXT_texture_lod_bias.txt).

Answer (score 0):

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
```

Comment: I tried that but my texture renders blank. I can't find what's wrong

Comment: @CodeFlakes:  That IS how you set up mipmapping.  If it renders blank then most likely you don't have any mipmaps in your texture?  Do you generate them? Use glGenerateMipmapOES.

Comment: Actually what I want is not use mipmap but if I don't unless I select GL_NEAREST or GL_LINEAR my texture is white. Sorry if this is a silly remark. I'll check glGenerateMipmapOES. Thanks